# Is there a way to supress notifications during game?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-notifications

I am making a 2D android game with Unity. Whenever I play messenger and other notifications pops up and overlay game screen. Is there any way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the user can in a per app basis block notifications from showing, but from a developer point of view there's nothing we can do about it.